# How to call a parent function from a child - react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm struggling to find a solution to my problem , but i cannot find it anywhere . So my question is how to call a parent function from a child . The function has to be passed in a **onPress={()}** inside the child

**Parent.js**

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loading: true };
    this.state = { active: 'active' };
    this.openDrawer = this.openDrawerButtonFunction.bind(this);
    this.callParent = this.callParent.bind(this)

       }

     callParent = () => {
     console.log('I am your father')   }
```

**Child.js**

```
     <Avatar
      avatarStyle={{ height: 50 }}
      onPress={() => { this.onPressAvatar() }}
      source={require('../../assets/images/dav-r.jpeg')} />

      onPressAvatar = () => {
      console.log('press on avatar');
        this.props.callParent.bind(this)
```

}

Comment: Please show your full code, the part which you're including the child component in your parent component.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a common mis-understanding, so you're in good hands.

You're going to utilize `Props` to accomplish calling a parent function to a child.

Naturally, the child knows **not** of the parent's functions. When you need to do something in the child Component, and bubble it up to the parent function, you just need to pass the function as a prop.

***Example***

**ParentComponent.js**

```
...

doSomething(x){
   console.log(x);
}

render(){
   return(
      <ChildComponent functionPropNameHere={this.doSomething}/>
   )
}
```

**ChildComponent.js**

```
someFunctionInChildComponent(){
   this.props.functionPropNameHere('placeholder for x');
}
```

When you run the function `someFunctionInChildComponent()`, it will call the `Prop` called `functionPropNameHere` which then moves to the parent component to call the function there. The input `x` will be `placeholder for x` in this example.

Comment: Yep , you have answered my question . Cheers mate !

Comment: this is a horrible design on the react native's part! Doesn't really help when you have complex applications such as screens containing components and also providing various utility functions for popups etc.

Answer (score 2):

**In the parent render function**

```
parentfunction(info){
   alert(info)
}


render(){
      return(
       //bla bla bla
       <Child functionToPass={this.parentfunction}/>
       //bla bla bla
      )
    }
```

**In the child**

```
callparentfunction(){
this.props.functiontoPass('Hello from the child')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the parent function as a prop to the child. [More info here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Parent.js

```
function doSomething(info){
   console.log("Parent Function")
}

render(){
   return(
      <ChildComponent functionPropNameHere={doSomething()}/>
   )
}
```

Child.js

```
function callparentfunction(){
props.functionPropNameHere()
}
```